# use of \paragraph in abstract elsarticle

Tags: paragraphs, abstract, elsarticle, front-matter

I am using `elsarticle` class to prepare a preprint. For this, I would like to use structured abstract i.e., use of different paragraph headings in the abstract. However, using `\paragraph` result in one blank page before the title page and last paragraph command is not shown in the final output. I don't really know where should I look. Alternatively, I can achieve the desired results by simply using italic text, however, it would be good to know the problem and the fix if any.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
\paragraph{Introduction}
\paragraph{Conclusions}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The abstract of a journal article should generally contain no more than 100 to 120 words. How much "structure" can one possibly provide for a text piece that contains no more than 5 to 8 sentences?!

Comment: `\paragraph` is a level 4 heading and should only be used as part of a hierarchy section.subsection,subsubsection,paragraph

Comment: @Mico I agree, however, it has becoming more common in some journals i.e. 1-2 lines for each of Introduction, Method, Results, Conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\paragraph`, but not as the first object in the abstract.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
\mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}% unless you have text before \paragraph
\paragraph{Introduction}
Intro
\paragraph{Conclusions}
Conc
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

However, I see no real reason for such an approach: the abstract should be short and sharp.

In your example, the blank page is generated by `\paragraph` being the first object in the abstract; the second `\paragraph` doesn't show because no text follows it (it happens also if you have `\paragraph{Foo}` and no text up to `\end{document}`.

With `\mbox{}\par` we generate a dummy paragraph, but we need to back up one line.